Should I write an outline of proof/method of proof in a paper?
Here is a question of whether I should write a subsection called "outline of proof"/"method of proof" in a paper I am writing. I note that there is a similar question (Mathematical Writing: Proof Outlines/Overview in a Paper), but my reason of asking is different from the OP there.
I am currently writing the intro of a (pure math) paper (the math part is done), which consists of the subsections "Main results" and "Outline". I plan to add a subsection called "Method of proof" after "Main results" and before "Outline" in the intro.
The reason of adding this subsection are to briefly explain the method/approach I use in the current paper to the problem I am considering, compare the approaches I am using and I used in my previous papers, point out their differences and present a related intermediate result.
On one hand, I feel it is necessary to add this subsection because I want to let the readers, especially the editor(s) and the referee(s), know that why I used a different approach and a subtle difference between the two approaches. On the other hand, however, I am not sure if the readers, including the editor(s) and the referee(s), are interested to know. While the subsections "Main results" and "Outline" are a must in the intro, "Method of proof" is not. I try to be as concise as possible while conveying the idea and the approach in a comprehensible way.
Of course, I could just write and add the subsection and then submit to see whether the editor and the referee like it or not. But I want to know, in general, do they like it? After all, they are experts in the field and perhaps don't bother to know why I do it in the way I did.
I am not sure if the following information is useful or relevant: the paper has 60 pages. The results and its proofs are about 45 pages.

If I would like to understand such paper, definitely comprehensive descriptions of proof strategies would help me a lot.

"I want to let the readers, especially the editor(s) and the referee(s), know that [...] I used a different approach and a subtle difference between the two approaches." Then it makes sense to include this subsection. The editors and the referees would hardly be likelier to reject the paper because of this subsection, even if they request that it be removed.

Even if one doesn't want to understand a paper, one often wants to understand the method of proof and its relationship to previous approaches. This is often crucial to evaluate the quality of the paper for refereeing decisions and other purposes, and also helpful to evaluate if you want to read the paper further.

By all means you should. As a referee, I have often been frustrated by papers which have long and technical proofs and no guide to see the forest among the trees.

A comparison of your method to previous methods is always useful. I think it is often described in the introduction, maybe in a more informal way than you suggest, i.e. without a separate header or subsection. But you can do whatever you want! (P.S. I've heard the (meaningless) rule that an introduction should take up roughly 20% of the length of the paper, so your ratio is not so far off.)
